# Very Unusual Margin Appears Always in Internet Explorer [CSS]

Tags: css, internet-explorer, xhtml, margin

Only in Internet Explorer does this occur: I'm getting an additional margin (of 19 pixels) below a fieldset and I can't seem to see why, whatever I try! Try it for yourself, take a look at http://theshrop.com/d/call_us_or_call_in.php. To aid I've added a grid and some background colours. The fieldset should have a 1.125em bottom margin and it does in Safari, Firefox etc. It has an extra 19 pixels in Internet Explorer? I've given the fieldset a width and height so it hasLayout, hope this helps.

```
body{
color:#171717;
font:1em/1.125em Georgia,serif;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
/*   */
fieldset{
background:fuchsia;
border:0 solid green;
border-width:0.0625em 0;
height:19.125em;
margin:0 0 1.125em;
padding:3.3125em 1.125em 1.0625em;
position:relative;
width:31.5em;
}
/*   */
form dl{
margin:0;
}
form dl dd{
/*       */
height:2.25em;
margin:0 0 1.125em;
position:relative;
/*       */
}
form dl dt{
margin:0 0 1.125em;
}
/*   */
form dl dt+dd+dt+dd{
height:7.875em;
} 
/*   */
form dl+div{
line-height:2.25em;
/*       */
margin:0;
padding:0;
/*       */
}
h3{
color:#701;
font:bold 1em/1.125em Helvetica,Arial,serif;
margin:0 0 1.125em;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
input[type=text]{
border:0.0625em solid #171717;
font:1em/1.125em Georgia,serif;
height:1.125em;
margin:0;
padding:0.5em 1.0625em;
/*       */
position:absolute;
top:0;
/*       */
}
/*   */
legend{
background:aqua;
margin:1.0625em 0 1.125em;
padding:0;
position:absolute;
top:0;
}
/*   */
p{
background:lime;
margin:0 0 1.125em;
}
textarea{
border:0.0625em solid #171717;
font:1em/1.125em Georgia,serif;
height:6.75em;
margin:0;
padding:0.5em 1.0625em;
/*       */
position:absolute;
top:0;
/*       */
}
.Address{
margin:0 0 1.125em;
}
.Address dd{
margin:0;
}
.Address dt{
display:none;
}
.Address dt+dd+dt+dd{
display:inline;
}
.Address dt+dd+dt+dd+dt+dd+dt+dd{
display:block;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
.Bad{
background:#dbb;
color:#901;
}
.Calendar{
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.Calendar dd{
background:#701;
font:bold 0.5625em/2em Helvetica,Arial,serif;
margin:0;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
.Calendar dl{
border:0 solid #111;
border-width:0.0625em 0.125em 0.125em 0.0625em;
float:left;
margin:-0.0625em 1em 1em 1.0625em;
width:3.375em;
}
.Calendar dt{
display:none;
}
.Calendar dt+dd+dt+dd{
background:#fff;
color:#171717;
font:1em/2.25em Georgia,serif;
margin:0;
}
.Calendar h4{
float:right;
font:1em/1.125em Georgia,serif;
margin:0 0 1.125em;
width:10.125em;
}
.Calendar li{
clear:both;
}
.Calendar p{
float:right;
font:1em/1.125em Georgia,serif;
width:10.125em;
}
.Good{
background:#bdb;
color:#091;
}
.Left{
float:left;
margin:0 0.5625em 0 1.125em;
}
.Message{
border-style:solid;
border-width:0.0625em;
margin:0 0 1.125em;
padding:1em 1.0625em 0;
}
.Message p{
margin:0 0 1.0625em;
padding:0.0625em 0 0;
}
.Narrow{
width:15.75em;
}
.Narrow input[type=text]{
width:13.5em;
}
.Right{
float:right;
margin:0 1.125em 0 0.5625em;
}
.Wide{
/*       */
background:gray;
/*       */
width:31.5em;
}
.Wide input[type=text]{
width:29.25em;
}
.Wide textarea{
width:29.25em;
}
.Wrapper{
background:url(../i/grid_w18_h18.png);
margin:0 auto;
overflow:hidden;
padding:1.125em 0 0;
position:relative;
width:50.625em;
}
#Blackboard{
background:#171717;
color:#fff;
margin:1.125em 0 0;
min-width:50.625em;
}
#Blackboard a{
background:#111;
color:#fff;
}
#Blackboard h3{
color:#fff;
}
#Blackboard div>p{
font:1.5em/1.5em Georgia,serif;
}
#Footer{
background:#901;
clear:both;
color:#fff;
min-width:50.625em;
}
#Footer h3{
color:#fff;
}
#Google_Copilot ol{
padding:0;
}
#Google_Copilot ol li{
list-style:none;
margin:0 0 1.125em;
padding:0; /* I.E.7 Fix  */
}
#Google_Map{
height:23.625em;
margin:0 0 1.125em;
width:31.5em;
}
#Google_Query dt{
/*     display:none; */
}
#Header{
background:#901;
min-width:50.625em;
}
#Header h1{
background:url(../i/the_shropshire_arms_w288_h72.gif) no-repeat 0 2.8125em;
font:1em/1.125em serif;
height:7.875em;
margin:0 0 0 0.5625em;
width:18em;
}
#Header h1 a{
display:none;
}
#Header h2{
background-color:#933;
display:inline;
font:1em/2.25em Georgia,serif;
left:0;
margin:1.125em 0 0 0.5625em;
padding:0 0.5625em;
position:absolute;
top:0;
}
#Header h2 a{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
}
#Header h2 a span{
text-decoration:underline;
}
#Header ul{
list-style:none;
height:2.25em;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#Header ul li{
display:inline; /* I.E.7 Fix  */
}
#Header ul li a{
background:#fff;
color:#000;
float:left;
line-height:2.25em;
margin:0 0 0 0.5625em;
padding:0 0.5625em;
text-decoration:none;
}
#Header .Wrapper{
background:url(../i/shield_w126_h126.gif) no-repeat 42.1875em 1.6875em;
}
```

This post could get stupidly long so I'll provide a link to the Web page rather than post the HTML: http://theshrop.com/d/call_us_or_call_in.php

I really appreciate answers and all who contribute, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it's hard to even tell what's going on, and that page looks different in every browser I've tried.

A few tips though:

1 - All browsers have their own base margins etc for elements, so it's a good idea to use some sort of "reset" css, which makes every margin/padding 0, so that when you specify it with your own css, every browser interprets the same amount of margin/padding for an element. A very popular version of this was made by Eric Meyer: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/

2 - Setting the height can be part of the problem here. It's usually best to let the internal elements set the height, and just let the containing element flow naturally. In your case, everything inside of the fieldset should be telling it how high to be, instead of the fieldset having it's own height.

Just some general thoughts, hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried without height and it didn't work and tried with height so it hasLayout in I.E.  so it seems it has no effect, as said above.  Please be more specific with what browsers you've tried and what you actually see. It otherwise renders as expected in Safari, Mozilla on Mac, I.E.7 and Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: This hinted at the answer, it was the form field that appended the additional whitespace. To be precise there's an additional 1 pixel margin in Internet Explorer by default.

Although however, the above helped it did not provide the perfect answer. Browser testing is so we can set individual styles so a generic "reset sheet" is unnecessary. The site renders fine since I've corrected the code. An additional "reset sheet" is an unnecessary inclusion.

More over, the provided page is dated 2007. How many browsers have blossomed since and all distinguish their individual display differently.